# Does a PhoneGap plugin have to be packaged separately?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working on a new PhoneGap 3.* application. I'll require access to a number of native components. However, these components aren't of general usefulness; they're native libraries that we've built that the application needs to access.

In reading how to access this native code, it's obvious we need to write plugins. However, all of the docs suggest that these plugins need to be in their own git repositories. I don't see any information on building plugins without this requirement.

This is a problem for us. Most importantly, we don't use git, and that's not something that's negotiable (certainly not in the short term). Secondly, I'd sure love to have the native code reside in the same source tree as our phonegap code, since it's not going to be reused elsewhere.

Is there the option of dropping our native code inside of a phonegap project somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a requirement that you use git, it's just the way it's mostly done

If you for instance make your plugin and put it in the `plugins/` folder on your own to finish the installation do:

```
cordova plugin add plugins/com.example.test-plugin
```

The plugin installation is handled by [plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman) and is a good place to figure out more about how the plugins work.

For the case of local install it should basically turn out to adding a JSON file for your platform with a listing of the paths of plugins to install on build.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was able to make that work. One thing of note... it's probably not a great idea to put the plugin directly in the plugins directly, as it could be overwritten by plugman as it 'installs' the plugin. I created a 'plugindev' folder to hold my plugin code.

Answer (score -1):

**Before adding plugins to your application git command line tool is required.**

You could download and install git command line for `Mac OS X` in [here](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.8.3.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg&can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded). For `windows`, Download Git from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Then: git clone git://project.url.here

Then you can add plugin and try run the command like

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

Once successfully running the command, then your project directory that particular plugin supporting java script and Native java code will be generated.